# Eureka row to present view controller and return value in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, eureka-forms

I am looking for help in figuring out how to have a row in a MultivaluedSection present a view controller with a second Eureka form and return a value back to the MultivaluedSection row.  I've been able to get a regular ButtonRow to push a view controller using a segue, but I can't figure out not to get a value back to the row in the MultivaluedSection.  I'm not sure if the ButtonRow method supports returning values or not so I started looking for other solutions.  One I found is to use a custom presenter row (https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#custom-presenter-rows), but I don't understand how to make that work.

Here one thing I did find, but again, I don't understand how to put this all together:

Help creating simple Custom Presenter Row
      -  https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/716

Can someone either point me to a working sample or help walk me through getting this setup?

Comment: One other option I found was to use a ButtonRowWithPresent but again I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already pushing a new VC with a segue, then you might want to implement a protocol and define the functions to pass data back.

[Here](https://makeapppie.com/2016/06/27/using-segues-and-delegates-for-navigation-controllers-in-swift-3-0/) is a good tutorial with Navigation controllers where at the end a Protocol is added.

eg:

#### View one (could be the Form View Controller with the ButtonRow)

```
class FormVC: FormViewController , FooViewControllerDelegate{
    var text : String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    /// Delegate protocol callback implementation
    func myVCDidFinish(controller: FooViewController, text: String) {
        // Receive the data as a delegate
        self.text = text
        // In this case we also want to finish the view
        controller.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    /// This represents the prepare for segue mentioned as implemented in the question
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Act upon the segue we want from this VC
        // The string is defined in the storyboard, so it must be exactly the same
        if segue.identifier == "mySegue"{
            // Creating the second VC instance
            let vc = segue.destination as! FooViewController
            // Since this class is now a delegate, setup the delegate
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

#### View two (the pushed View controller)

```
protocol FooViewControllerDelegate {
    func myVCDidFinish(controller: FooViewController, text: String)
}

class FooViewController: UIViewController {
    /// Data
    var text : String!

    /// Set up an optional delegate
    var delegate:FooViewControllerDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Init label
        self.text = "Pushed view data to pass back
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding an answer again, as it was deleted. Please accept answer if it solved the problem in the OP.